# Does this vegetable make sense?

Tags: flora, underground, creature-design, fungi

This vegetable is a fungus grown by the people described in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/205889/what-weapons-would-fossorial-people-use). It is egg-shaped with no stalk, and is around 1m tall and 70cm across at the widest point. They can be, and often are, cultivated underground, though they are naturally found on the surface. Its spores grow in a gleba, and are large and grain-like. They are annual, and are planted in the spring, growing until autumn, when they are harvested. In nature, they rupture in autumn, letting their spores blow around over winter. How could this vegetable evolve and be cultivated?

Comment: you do realize they are going to have to grow something else to feed the fungus right?

Comment: "This vegetable is a fungus" no. Fungi are one of the kingdoms of life, plant is another. A fungus cannot be a vegetable and vice-versa, just as animal cannot be a bacteria.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw by "vegetable" i'm pretty sure the OP means the relaxed definition of  "Vegetables are parts of plants that are consumed by humans or other animals as food". They would call wheat a vegetable! And oranges! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law: Depends on context.  To a cook, mushrooms are vegetables.

Comment: @jamesqf I see now. Must be just like astrophysicists will call anything heavier than helium a metal just to spite the chemists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fungus would need a large "catchment" area that it drawn nutrients from.

A 1mx0.7m ovoid is about 0.24m3 in volume, thus about 55kg.
6m2 of perfectly-fertilized-and-watered compost bed, or about 30m2 of natural soil will suffice to nourish the fungus.

It would require a long history of specialised breeding to attain such a size, and for the spores in the gleba to be nutritious (or even not-deadly-toxic!), but this is a mere technicality.

Note that a 1-year cycle is *very* long for a sporing fungus. a 1-3 month cycle is more likely, and more efficient for the fungi. This would necessitate a correspondingly larger feed/root area for the fungus to attain that size.

Within these constraints, your <s>vegetable</s> fungus makes perfect sense.

Comment: Do you have a source for how much soil is needed to feed the fungi? I am not doubting you, it just seems weird to me that the answer is an area rather than a volume.

Comment: @ETam the fungi needs access to organic material *and oxygen* in the same place. However fungi do not have a vascular system that can transport oxygen from "lungs" to the needed feeding site. Fungal cells get their oxygen directly from the environment. Thus the feeding is a surface and near-surface effect where oxygen can naturally diffuse deep enough. For compost, about 8-12 inches.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a [giant truffle](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-truffle/), but a bit more elegant.