# What can you do with fungal spores?

Tags: flora, food, medieval, fungi

The spores in question come from the vegetables described in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/206215/does-this-vegetable-make-sense). More specifically, the spores are like grains, with a chitinous shell, small wings, and a nutritious flesh, akin to softer mushroom tissue, in which the actual spore is embedded. These spores are around 1cm long. The vegetable is just a fungus, and has the traits thereof. The people cultivating them have technology akin to medieval europe. What are some products that could plausibly be made from these spores? Please explain how the product could be made, and how a fungus could have the raw materials required for the product

Comment: Flour?  Muffins?

Comment: @Willk But could flour or muffins be made from a fungus?

Comment: What can you do with x? sounds rather open ended. How are you going to pick the best answer? Can you give a closed scope?

Comment: What you have described is a cereal grain: a spore surrounded by nutritious matter which in a cereal would be called endosperm surrounded by a hard shell which in a grain would be the seed coat.   So I proposed a grain use.  It did not seem worthy of a full answer,

Comment: @Willk A cereal grain is a plant, with plant-like features. This is a fungus, without those plant-like features

Comment: If you gave them to your hamster, maybe they could spew them as lethal darts }i{. More seriously, I agree with L.Dutch, adding on top that besides physical attributes, you give no chemical details. Pock, did you know that you get WILDLY different pancake textures and tastes as you choose wheat or buckwheat flour? As you currently state, I'd be willing to cook pancakes from your fungi :). Or a [fireproof material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IbWampaEcM), perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lots!

Well, *some.*

### Cuisine

If the spores are like grain, they'd probably get treated like other grains.

I imagine the spores are essentially long-grain rice that has a vaguely mushroomy flavor. Which is to say: people will probably go bonkers for them. As an example, I once had roommates who prepared an entire meal out of just 6 pounds of mushrooms.

How they can be prepared will depend in large part on whether the [gleba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleba) is encased in a hard peridiole. I'm going to assume they are, because that seems like it's more fun. So, imagine a coconut filled with mushroom-infused rice.

I imagine that cooking the gleba whole, by roasting, smoking, or boiling, will be a delicacy, kind of like [the Hawaiian pig-in-the-sand thing](https://www.curiouscuisiniere.com/kalua-pork/). Imagine every dinner guest gets their own piping-hot gleba filled with tender mushroom-flavored rice.

To prepare it, they might scrape the exterior of the peridiole clean, or not; unless the outer flesh is gross, bad-tasting, or toxic, family recipes will have a strong opinion about which way is better, and families with different opinions will have good-natured feuds over it. If you marry into a family that does it the opposite way, you and your spouse will have to strike some kind of bargain.

Then the glebas will be thrown into a pot of boiling water and covered, or thrown into a hot oven, or onto a grill, where they will boil, bake, or roast until the spores inside are tender. A good cook could probably tell you whether it's wise to puncture the peridiole and pour in some kind of flavorful liquid (or even alcohol) before cooking them; I am not that cook.

Then the glebas will be removed and set aside to cool, while side-dishes are prepared for plating. If there's a hard peridiole, people will invent a special kitchen implement for cutting them open without burning one's hands or chipping the peridiole, which would add unpleasant grit to the otherwise tender dish (people can lose teeth). Or, maybe the peridiole has softened, and so is eaten like the skin of a baked potato. Again, families will have *opinions*.

These things will be a seasonal delicacy, so: abundant and available to all in the autumn, and then increasingly rare and expensive as the seasons pass, until the next harvest. Depending on the volume of the harvest relative to consumption, and how quickly they spoil, rich people would enjoy them year-round, and most other people would just get to have a few of them each year during the harvest.

You haven't provided a name for the fungus, but there will probably be a slang term for rich people based on their seasonal availability, e.g. a "BLANK-eater" is someone who can afford to eat these BLANKs year-round, i.e. is wealthy. Anyone who eats one of these in the summer, before the harvest, is well-off: "to have one's June BLANK," is to consummate one's high position. These people might have the idiom, "[you can't have your BLANK and eat it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it)."

That's just the delicacy. As a flavorful grain, it'll get used in soups and stews and as a pilaf. Basically, anywhere rice and mushrooms are welcome.

As a fungus, it could be sharply aromatic, which could either be welcome (if the scent is pleasant), or the only drawback of this otherwise-versatile food. If the smell is unpleasant, people may handle it like they do [durian fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durian#Flavour_and_odour).

If these are cultivated widely, the annual Fall rupture may become the focus of cultural events, like [cherry-blossom festivals](https://nationalcherryblossomfestival.org/) in the real world.

#### Feed for farm animals

If the spores are *not* particularly delicious (which seems absurd), and resist incorporation into tasty meals, they might be used as feed for chickens and pigs.

### Not-cuisine

People will eat whatever is edible, but if the scent is strong and unpleasant, or if the chitinous covering on each spore is an insurmountable obstacle, folks will find other uses for them given how many are produced each year.

#### Woven mats & rugs

People could weave them into mats. (I imagine they'd need to be dried-out first.) I guess people have been [weaving floor mats for about 6,000 years](https://ultimatemats.com/blog/history-of-rubber-floor-mats). You could also see durable outerwear for field workers, or something like beaded curtains, or tapestries.

Note that the mat wouldn't be made *only* of the spores. At 1cm, they can't be woven. They would be woven *into* things to add thickness, durability, or decoration. If the spores are more spherical, people would punch holes through them like beads; if they're more like filaments, they'd just get woven in.

I suspect chitin won't take dye, so they'd tend to have similar coloring, with some natural variation in lightness, and possibly depending on how they have been desiccated.

#### Teaching & toys

If weaving happens -- or, indeed, if regular homes have any kind of container filled with them, either through cottage industry or as a consumer product -- they will inevitably get used for and by children. Some kids will likely be taught basic counting and arithmetic using these spores. Small, ubiquitous, uniform, non-toxic things tend to get treated that way.

Because they're all identical, kids will want to play with them, like marbles or wooden pegs. That's just how kids are. And as long as they remain non-toxic after whatever preparation they've gone through (and if they're inexpensive) people will not bother preventing kids from playing with them.

They'll get used as Monopoly money and other kinds of game counter, the one possible exception being games with real-money stakes, where, if they are round, they'll tend to roll around, which is decidedly *unwelcome* at the poker table.

#### Adhesive

If the gleba is sticky and large, it may be a good source for adhesive. (I doubt it would be a good permanent adhesive, but there are occasions that call for temporary adhesives.)

Answer (score 0):

If the chitinous shell is tough and the wings are indigestible, then I'd expect that some sort of fermentation would be used to separate shell and wings from the flesh.  Think Tofu. the flesh is kind of dissolved and drained from the husks and then solidified again.  Not like Gelatin. More akin to polymerization, but for protein and not plastics. Turning the spores into a high protein source.

And, the spores might be dried whole.  Then rolled to knock the wings off unless its easy to somehow twist the wings off before drying. These would be eaten like berries and stored for long periods of time.  They might also be pummeled to break up the shells which can be separated by tossing in the air like separating chaff from wheat. This would yield the inner dried inner flesh and could be rehydrated like dried mushrooms and used for meals.  Or ground into a powder, like a flour for baking.  Probably not by itself, but mixed with other flours to add protein or whatever nutrients are plentiful in the spore.  Something like medieval Horse Bread -- a mix of just about everything from pea flours to nuts.

Then, the spores might be pickled.  Softening the shell.

The ways the spores are preserved reflects the available technologies to create and store food, but to also maximize the nutritional benefit of the spores to keep people healthy over the winter months.