# Clothing for Fossorial People

Tags: fantasy-races, medieval, clothing, underground

The fossorial people are small humanoids. They have hair on their head, but it only grows to around shoulder length. They also have similar hair on their chest, hands, and feet. This hair can resist dirt. Their skeletal characteristics are described [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/205889/what-weapons-would-fossorial-people-use). What clothing would be best at resisting dirt while crawling through or digging dirt-tunnels, while still keeping the wearer warm in an environment akin to medieval Britain?

Comment: What does "resist dirt" mean?  Brown clothing?  Clothing sprayed with a hydrophobic coating?  Why do they habitually crawl through dirt tunnels if they care about resisting dirt?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like mole skin:  https://molepro.com/pages/mole-facts a very dense and fine fur

Comment: How deep do they dig?  Because as you dig deeper, temperatures get warmer and more stable.

Comment: note a fossorial species does not need to worry  much about warmth, dirt is incredibly thermally stable, thermal variation underground is controlled by depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why Wear Clothing at All?**
Consider normal nudity. If these people evolved to live underground, then they've probably grown accustomed to dirt, insects and the like. Clothing is a matter of culture more than anything else, and seeing as humanoids (bigger ones) have historically gotten along just fine & naked (Tierra del Fuego), there's no obvious reason why these people must wear clothing.

Apart from difficulty in obtaining materials, in the darkness, clothing won't be useful for signalling or decoration (since it's so dark) and anyway, everyone will just misplace their socks.

It's easier to go without!

Comment: Humans have been wearing clothing for a **long, long time**.  The *type* of clothes you wear is all about culture.  Those Yaghans in Tierra del Fuego smeared fish oil and animal fat all over themselves, and *constantly* kept fires burning (even in wooden canoes!)

Comment: @RonJohn -- That's exactly what I said! It's all cultural. And in our case, all ***human*** cultural. Other sophonts may and probably will behave differently!

Comment: No, it's **not** "all cultural".  Clothes are **damned practical** anywhere except the tropics.  Heck, even in the tropics, they're needed for light-skinned peoples.

Comment: @RonJohn -- "Practical" is entirely in the eye of the beholder, and thus more a matter of culture and tradition.

Comment: You walk in the snow with nothing but the skin you were born in, and -- fish oil and fires or not -- you'll see what a bunch of idiots the Yaghans were.  Or the blistering summer sun.  Maybe try a forest covered in underbrush. Bottom line: clothes are *practical*.

Comment: the biggest advantage clothing has is pockets, the big down side of the Yaghans lifestyle is staying warm for them is a frequent, repetitive, low return investment, whereas cloths are a small investment with high long lasting return. Its the difference between renting a bike for 20 becks a day everyday to go to work  vs just buying a bike that will last years for 100 bucks. clothes are a much better use of your time and energy to achieve the same goal, if the goal is staying warm.

Answer (score 5):

The only fibers, or fiber like structures, which they can access underground are roots.

The roots of adequate diameter can be dried and woven together to produce a very rough fabric, at most resembling yuta bags, which can offer some protection against contact with the underground. This is what they probably actually need, since a few meters underground temperature is pretty much constant all year long with very small fluctuations when compared to the changes above ground.