# What would the fossorial people's senses be like?

Tags: humanoid, underground, senses

The fossorial people are described partly [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/205889/what-weapons-would-fossorial-people-use). They are adapted for life underground. While they must go aboveground for wood and fruit, they prefer to stay underground, and have a diet of mostly roots and digging creatures. They are specifically adapted to dig for roots, collect fruit from surface trees, and fabricate tools underground. They use fire for cooking, but nothing more. They evolved from apes, and characteristics of the . What is the most plausible way for them to sense the world, either underground or on the surface?

Comment: I'm new here but would it be better to just copy/paste the text from your other question to complete this question? Does doing it this way help the stack somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Echolocation** Many humans have developed a form of echolocation in them, see this [link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_echolocation#:%7E:text=Human%20echolocation%20is%20the%20ability,clicking%20noises%20with%20their%20mouths.).
If humans can do that, so can the fossorial people. Their throat has developed in such a way that it can create clicking noises better than ours, and has developed their senses to detect the echoes.

**Big eyes/pupils**
Maybe they also have bigger eyes to get more light, with a translucent eyelid to use when they come aboveground to protect their eyes from direct light.

**Bigger ears** too for better listening.

**Micro-fibers on skin** Just like many other animals who have micro-fibers on their skin to detect disturbances in the nearby environment.